# Still getting data after expire SANCTUM

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

Hi I edit the config/sanctum.php , I add a value for 1 min, to test if I will get an error after expiration. when I send a request after 3 mins from my SPA app, I was able to get the details. I expected that it will throw an error or some status code 422 or whatever the status code is being thrown by the laravel.

**'expiration' => 1**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Stateful Domains
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Requests from the following domains / hosts will receive stateful API
    | authentication cookies. Typically, these should include your local
    | and production domains which access your API via a frontend SPA.
    |
    */

    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', 'localhost,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1')),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Expiration Minutes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value controls the number of minutes until an issued token will be
    | considered expired. If this value is null, personal access tokens do
    | not expire. This won't tweak the lifetime of first-party sessions.
    |
    */

    'expiration' => 1,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sanctum Middleware
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When authenticating your first-party SPA with Sanctum you may need to
    | customize some of the middleware Sanctum uses while processing the
    | request. You may change the middleware listed below as required.
    |
    */

    'middleware' => [
        'verify_csrf_token' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        'encrypt_cookies' => App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    ],

];
```

did I miss something in the configuration or elsewhere?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

clean your cache configuration and test it again

```
php artisan config:cache
```

then

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

i think it can resolve your problem .

Comment: Not working, I can still request data after 1 min

Answer (score 0):

For your question you can try to change the values of  expiration

```
   'expiration' => 120
```

Or make

```
   'expiration' => null
```

If this value is null, personal access tokens do| not expire.